# Do the Bitlocker Keys Clear from Physical Memory after Shutdown?

Tags: encryption, bitlocker, forensics

It is claimed that [Passware Kit Forensic](http://www.lostpassword.com/kit-forensic.htm) can recover passwords or keys of drives encrypted by Bitlocker. This needs an image of the encrypted drive plus a so-called **Physical Memory** image of the target machine.

I have lost the password of my drive (one of the partitions) about five days ago and after that, the Windows has shut down several times.

Now, can I use the solution Passware Inc. offers? More specifically, after several system shutdowns, is there any useful data inside the **Physical Memory**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, can I use the solution Passware Inc. offers? More specifically, after several system shutdowns, is there any useful data inside the Physical Memory?

No.

Data stored in physical memory degrades ([and fairly quickly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_boot_attack)) after power is removed.  After a few minutes (at normal room temperature) any data that was in RAM is beyond recovery.

Additionally, given that it sounds like the machine has been booted up since, the memory locations that once did contain the encryption keys will have had different data written to them.

The only way to get your data back is to find/remember the password, or crack it with a password cracker.  Depending on how long your password was, cracking it may not be feasible.